# Intellij Service Diagram: No service modules found for supported web frameworks

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot module opened in Intellij 2021.2 and want to create the Service Diagram for it, see new feature description: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/06/intellij-idea-eap-6/#microservices_diagram

When opening the Service Diagram, an empty tab opens in and the error message "No service modules found for supported web frameworks" appears. My source, target folders, etc. and Spring configuration files look configured correctly. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: If you still haven't solved this issue, you could contact the IDEA support via IDE main menu `Help | Contact Support` with the log `Help | Show Log in...` for help.